# MapView regions zoom level different in IOS 6

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, mkcoordinateregion

I have an app that uses MapKit to layout a map with annotations. I have a method that creates an MKCoordinateRegion that I assign to setRegion to adjust the zoom level of the map appropriately. But the zoom level in IOS 6 is lower than in IOS 5. When I run on IOS 5 the annotations are spaced nicely but in IOS 6 they are right out to the edges. If I turn up the scaling factor I can get the spacing in IOS 6 right but then in IOS 5 they are all jammed together in the middle.

```
- (MKCoordinateRegion)calculateRegion
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    double scaleValue = 1.5

    //set an initial value for coordinates from any annotation
    MyAnnotation *annotation = [self.annotations lastObject];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D max = annotation.coordinate;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D min = max;
    double latitude, longitude;

    for (MyAnnotation *annotation in self.annotations) {
        latitude = annotation.coordinate.latitude;
        longitude = annotation.coordinate.longitude;
        if (latitude > max.latitude) max.latitude = latitude;
        else if (latitude < min.latitude) min.latitude = latitude;
        if (longitude > max.longitude) max.longitude = longitude;
        else if (longitude < min.longitude) min.longitude = longitude;
    }

    // set the center of the mapview
    region.center.latitude = (max.latitude + min.latitude) / 2;
    region.center.longitude = (max.longitude + min.longitude) / 2;

    // set the span to be larger than the max values to add some padding around pins
    region.span.latitudeDelta = (max.latitude - min.latitude) * scaleValue;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = (max.longitude - min.longitude) * scaleValue;

    MKCoordinateRegion regionThatFits = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
    region = regionThatFits;

return region;
}
```

Setting the scaleFactor above 2.0 works good for IOS 6 and 1.3 works good for IOS 5. What is strange is the IOS 6 simulator displays the annotations the same way as in IOS 5. Its just on the iPhone 4S that I'm using for testing that it displays incorrectly. Is there something that has changed in IOS 6 that would affect the zoom level?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they changed the maximum zoom level in iOS 6.  I've heard that if you download Xcode 4.6 DP1 the resulting build will make them closer to the same (between iOS 5 and iOS 6).

Answer (score 0):

I found the zoom level improved in the simulator with Xcode 4.6.1 but still limited on real iOS 6 devices. That is until I updated those devices to iOS 6.1.3, now zoom seems to back to per iOS 6 levels.